# Binding Never updates for Listbox with checkbox that gets toggled when listitem is selected

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, listbox, datatemplate

So I've been trying to make a list item that will toggle a checkbox when the listbox is fired. I have been able to successfully do this when binding isn't involved, but once I add binding it never updates the binding, but still updates the ischecked on the checkbox. I want it to check the box and also update my binding of IsSelectedName, so that I know that the user checked it. Also if I click right on the checkbox IsSelectedName gets updated. Here is the simplest version of my code:

```
        <ListBox Grid.Column="1" Margin="20" ItemsSource="{Binding listitems}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox Name="CheckboxIsSelected" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelectedName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </StackPanel>
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="CheckboxIsSelected" Property="IsChecked" Value="True"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Thanks in advance

Here is the View Model:

```
public class ListTestVM
{
    public List<listem> listitems { get; set; }
    public ListTestVM()
    {
        listitems = new List<listem>()
        {
            new listem(){ Name = "Test", IsSelectedName = false },
            new listem(){ Name = "Test1", IsSelectedName = true },
            new listem(){ Name = "Test2", IsSelectedName = false },
            new listem(){ Name = "Test3", IsSelectedName = true }
        };
    }
}
```

Here is the list item class:

```
public class listem :INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _IsSelectedName;
    public bool IsSelectedName
    {
        get { return _IsSelectedName; }
        set
        {
            _IsSelectedName = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("IsSelectedName");
        }
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged and make the selected item a backing field so you can NotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: I have added that and it still doesn't work. I've updated my question

Answer (score 1):

For listItem Property Use ObservableCollection Type like this:

```
public ObservableCollection<listem> listitems { get; set; }
```

and in your ListBox DataTemplate Set binding mode to TwoWayeMode like this:

```
<CheckBox Name="CheckboxIsSelected" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelectedName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

and Remove Your triggers

Comment: your answer was very close to what I was looking for. If you update your answer to say something about getting rid of the stackpanel and textblock and putting the text in the checkbox instead. I'll give you credit

Answer (score 0):

Do you use the INotifyPropertyChanged interface on you baseclass? 
The triggering of the PropertyChanged is works?
I think that will be the key on your problem.

Comment: I added that and it still doesn't work. I've updated my question